# Visual Studio 2017 offline installer error -2147024809

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm running this command from a BAT file which is in the same directory as the vs_Community.exe bootstrapper file.

```
vs_Community.exe --layout C:\vs2017offline --add 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliTrace.FrontEnd 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat
Component.Android.NDK.R13B Component.Android.SDK23 
Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API23.V2
Component.JavaJDK Component.HAXM Component.Xamarin 
Component.Xamarin.Inspector Component.Xamarin.Profiler 
Component.Xamarin.RemotedSimulator 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Phone.Emulator.15063 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.15063.UWP 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin
--lang en-US
```

The bootstrapper opens up fine and starts doing its thing with the message "Give us a minute. We'll be done soon" or something rather, and then exits suddenly.

Looking in %TEMP%, I find there's a log generated with this at the end:

> activityId "2cf9a512-9da4-480c-8a20-ec056a4eb707" --InstallerPath "C:\vs2017offline\b.mrg\vs_installer.opc"'.
>   VisualStudio Bootstrapper:30/04/2017 1:18:04 PM: Unable to parse the json file since it not exists: 0
>   VisualStudio Bootstrapper:30/04/2017 1:18:04 PM: Vs setup process C:\vs2017offline\b.mrg\resources\app\layout\setup.exe started. All done.
>   VisualStudio Bootstrapper:30/04/2017 1:18:04 PM: Waiting for setup process to complete...
>   VisualStudio Bootstrapper:30/04/2017 1:18:04 PM: Vs setup process exited with code -2147024809
>   VisualStudio Bootstrapper:30/04/2017 1:18:07 PM: Bootstrapper Successfully completed.

My C:\vs2017offline folder contains a folder called 'certificates' and a JSON file called 'vs_installer.version.json', and nothing else.

Comment: -2147024809 = invalid arguments. so check that the names are fine

Comment: I've checked each of the workload/component names and they seem fine. Would be useful if the error log says exactly which name is invalid.

Comment: you have some spaces in the names, this could be an issue

Comment: Could you be bit more specific as to which names you see spaces in? I don't see any spaces. For eg, `Component.JavaJDK Component.HAXM Component.Xamarin` are three different names and therefore have a space between them.

Comment: ok, check the names against this list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise

Comment: Did that after your first comment. All good. Also, that link is to the enterprise edition. I'm using Community.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting "Vs setup process exited with code -2147024809".
I was specifying multiple Workloads plus the Recommended and Optional Components for each Workload. Some components were the same in multiple Workloads.

I removed duplicate "--add component" entries to ensure that each Component was added at most once.

That finally allowed vs_professional.exe to download the desired content.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I removed duplicate --add component entries". How did you do this? I don't see duplicate names in the command I'm issuing, so how do I specify to ignore duplicates?